# How can I import ebooks using Configurator

Tags: ebook, apple-configurator

I have a small fleet of iPad Minis that I manage with Configurator.  When I purchase apps through the Volume Purchase Program and inmport a spreadsheet into Configurator to manage them.

Does the same feature set exist for ebooks?  I have purchased an ebook through VPP and wish to deploy them in a similar fashio to my iPads.

Users do not have Apple IDs, but do have Google Apps for Education accounts.

Comment: What app are yoiu using to read the ebooks? and are they under DRM?

Comment: No app yet, this is the first time an ebook has been requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to DRM restrictions, Apple Configurator cannot send eBooks to any iOS device. The only way to do this is to either email the eBooks to the iPads and download them from there or to use iTunes (it won't require an Apple ID to do this).

Comment: This is extra difficult to manage when the devices are locked down, disabling signing into iTunes and disabling in app purchases.